# Outlook Calendar Auto Decline Conflict for Specific Appointments

Tags: automation, outlook, calendar

Hoping someone can help me figure this out. How do you auto decline calendar events that conflict with specific event?

I can't blanket auto decline conflicts since there are times when the new request takes priority over the original calendar event so the original has to be moved.

However there are situations that arise that I need to block out time (3-4 hours) from people sending meeting requests. Generally when this block of time starts I will be away from my computer so I can't manually decline the meeting. Since many don't look at other's calendars to see if they are available I've had several people get mad at me for not attending a meeting that they scheduled 15 minutes to 1 hour before it started.

Before some one goes and says just download the app for during these times, I end up in areas with limited to no cellular service so I won't know when a meeting request comes in. Tried that already.

So to reiterate how do I set up auto-decline for specific appointments and not generalized?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while trying to solve a calendar auto-accept rules issue for myself.

If you have Office 365 licensing you may be able to use Power Automate to help with your issue. It can help to automate many tasks with Office by default without additional licensing. https://powerautomate.microsoft.com

In your case, I'd create an automated flow something like this:
(note: where it says [dynamic] below, click into the field, search for the text under the pop-up, and click on the item to add it)
(note 2: click "+ New step" button at the bottom between each numbered step below)

1. When a new event is created (V3)

   - Choose your Calendar ID (likely just "Calendar")
2. Get calendar view of events (V3)

   - Calendar Id
   - Start time: [dynamic] Start Time
   - End time: [dynamic] End Time
3. Filter Array

   - From: [dynamic] value (Get calendar view of events V3)
   - [dynamic] Subject (Get calendar view of events V3) "is not equal to" 'My subject'
4. Condition

   - length(body('Filter_array')) "is less than or equal to" 0
   - If yes (do nothing)
   - If no

     - Respond to an event invite
     - Event Id: [dynamic] Id (Get calendar view of events V3)
     - Response: Decline

Best of luck!

Disclaimer - I have not tested the flow above and it may need some additional work to get it functional especially the filter array portion. I'll update after I can do some tests with my own new flows.
Some points adapted from this blog: https://quickbites.dev/2020/11/26/my-calendar-manager/